# Element of array giving random num c++

Tags: c++

```
int main() {

    ifstream inFile("nums-1.txt");

    // Checks if the file opened successfully
    if (inFile.fail())
        cout << "Fail to open the file!" << endl;

    int value = 0, searchForInt, size = 0;
    int numsArray[size];

    // Assigns each values to the array and determine size
    while (inFile >> value)
    {
        numsArray[size] = value;
        size++;
    }

    cout << "Enter an integer to search for:" << endl;
    cin >> searchForInt;

    cout << "This array has " << size << " items." << endl;
    cout << "The array entered by the user is as follows: ";

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        cout << numsArray[i] << " ";
    }


    inFile.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
The array entered by the user is as follows: 22 -4 5 100 39 20 -1348122768 32767 -1348122768 32767 -1348122768 32767
```

What I want to output:

```
The array entered by the user is as follows: 22 -4 5 100 39 20 88 10 55 3 10 78 <- These are the values in the secondary file.
```

I have a few 12 values in the file that I opened (nums-1.txt) and it's reading with no problem. The problem is when I try to output the whole array through a for loop, it displays until the 8th element and after that it displays random numbers for the element 9-12.

Comment: In `int value = 0, searchForInt, size = 0;
int numsArray[size];`, ask yourself, how many elements can `numsArray` hold.

Comment: Arrays have fixed size. You need to give this fixed size at the declaration `int numArray[size];`. You cannot increase the size later. If you want to do that use `std::vector` with its `push_back` method instead of the array.

Comment: `numsArray[size] = value;` will always fail, because legal locations in the array are 0 to size-1.

Comment: My advice is use `std::vector<int> numsArray;` instead of `int numsArray[size];`  then change `numsArray[size] = value;` to `numsArray.push_back(value).` also make sure you add `#include <vector>`

Comment: BTW, you get random numbers because of Undefined Behavior. You declared your array to store 0 items. Putting any more than `0` items in the array is UB.

Answer (score 1):

Like the other comments say, use `std::vector`. You are using undefined behavior when loading numbers into your array.

```
int value, searchForInt = 0;
std::vector<int> numsArray;

while (inFile >> value)
{
    numsArray.push_back(value);
}
// ...
cout << "This array has " << numsArray.size() << " items." << endl;
cout << "The array entered by the user is as follows: ";

for (int i = 0; i < numsArray.size(); i++)
{
    cout << numsArray[i] << " ";
}
```